# Report on Pushed Opportunities this month

Tags: reporting, opportunity, dashboard, history-tracking

I am trying to create the report on the Pushed Opportunities this month as shown below

[image]

I enabled the History Trending in the setup for the Opportunity object and I didnot enable tracking an extra fields as by default the `The Amount, Close Date, Forecast Category, Probability and Stage fields are always trended` are tracked. In the reports I tried to create the Opportunities with Historical trending report type

[image]

But can anyone please help what should I be passing in the Close date as a filter so it shows  Pushed Opportunities this month